# Extracting keys values from scripting.dictionary into a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm extracting the keys values from g (object) fine, but they are overwriting each other in the M range, which I don't understand because it should be looking for the offset?  I'm clearly missing something. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
With wbkVer.Worksheets(1)
    Set g = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")   
    Set rngChasssSrc = wbkCS.Worksheets(2).Range("Z3:Z20")
    Set rngchassis = wbkVer.Worksheets(1).Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
For Each k In rngChasssSrc
    tmp = Trim(Right(k.Value, 7))
    If Not IsEmpty(tmp) Then g(tmp) = g(tmp) + 1
Next k
For Each u In g.Keys()
    rngchassis.Value = u
Next u
End With
```

**FINAL CODE:**

```
With wbkVer.Worksheets(1)
    Set g = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngChasssSrc = wbkCS.Worksheets(2).Range("Z3:Z20")
    Set rngchassis = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    For Each k In rngChasssSrc
        If k > 0 then
        tmp = Trim(Right(k.Value, 7))
        If Not IsEmpty(tmp) Then g(tmp) = g(tmp) + 1
        End if
    Next k
    For Each u In g.Keys()
        rngchassis.Value = u
        Set rngchassis = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next u
End With
```

Comment: Add `Else g.Add tmp, 1` after your line `If Not IsEmpty(tmp) Then g(tmp) = g(tmp) + 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> rngchassis.Value = u

The problem is that you are not incrementing the destination cell and hence it keeps overwriting it :)

**Untested** - Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim lRow As Long

    With wbkVer.Worksheets(1)
        Set g = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        Set rngChasssSrc = wbkCS.Worksheets(2).Range("Z3:Z20")

        '~~> Find Last Row in Col M for writing
        lRow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        For Each k In rngChasssSrc
            tmp = Trim(Right(k.Value, 7))
            If Not IsEmpty(tmp) Then g(tmp) = g(tmp) + 1
        Next k
        For Each u In g.Keys()
            .Range("M" & lRow).Value = u
            lRow = lRow + 1
        Next u
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

BTW, your above code can also be written as (Note resetting the range)

```
With wbkVer.Worksheets(1)
    Set g = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngChasssSrc = wbkCS.Worksheets(2).Range("Z3:Z20")
    Set rngchassis = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    For Each k In rngChasssSrc
        tmp = Trim(Right(k.Value, 7))
        If Not IsEmpty(tmp) Then g(tmp) = g(tmp) + 1
    Next k

    For Each u In g.Keys()
        rngchassis.Value = u
        Set rngchassis = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next u
End With
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot, will post again shortly.  Thanks!

Comment: I have included `Option Explicit` at the top of the code. I am assuming that you already have declared `g`, `rngChasssSrc`, `k` etc elsewhere in the module. If you have not declared them then you will get an error. To test it temporarily, you may remove `Option Explicit` But in the final code, I would recommend declaring those variables :)

Comment: I already had option explicit. :)   I tested it and now it's not showing anything (not overwriting either).

Comment: Can you debug and check what is the value that you are getting for `lRow`

Comment: The 2nd one worked!  I did add a quick check for blank cells, but outside of that it worked.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The `For Each u ...` loop can be replaced with

```
rngchassis.Resize(g.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(g.Keys)
```